# Does the 'at' command require a full path to the script's name?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Sometimes I use the `at` command to run a Bash script one time like this:

```
at -f goscript 8:00pm
```

(Execs need me to run a report at a time not in `crontab`.)

Is that the correct syntax? Or do I need `at -f /path/to/goscript 8:00pm`?

Does `at` require the full path to the filename like `cron` does? If my script is in `/path/to/goscript` will the above command run correctly? Assuming the first line of `goscript` is `#!/bin/bash`.

I did find this from `man at`:

> "**The working directory**,  the  environment  (except  for  the variables  BASH_VERSINFO,  DISPLAY,  EUID,  GROUPS, SHELLOPTS, TERM, UID, and _) and the umask are retained from the time of invocation."

Answer (score 1):

The `at` command doesn't need to be given an absolute path if you are running it from the same location.

If you are running it from the same location where you have your script just give the script's name.

Comment: I removed the "unless" in the first sentence since reading the second sentence I think that's what you actually meant, am I right? If not obviously revert my edit.